# PhpMailer, sent attachment as other name

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use phpmailer for sending email with attachment

```
    file = "/path/bla.csv";


    require 'class.phpmailer.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    // some oprtions here

    $mail->AddAttachment($file);

    $mail->Send();
```

So, if use this code, email is sended with attach file, and file name is: `bla.csv`

There is possible to change attach file name without renaming real file? that is, I need sent `bla.csv` file, but sent is as name `some_other_name.csv`

How to make this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pass the desired name as second parameter

```
$mail->AddAttachment($file, "newName.csv");
```