# Add date to attachment in PHP mailer SMTP

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to add the date to a file which is emailed using SMTP in php. What i need is to add the date to the file name sent in the email, without changing the file name on the server. So my code still looks for 'file.csv' but names it '(date)file.csv' in the email attachment.

```
$mail->addAttachment('file.csv');
```

I have already tried.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$filename = 'file'.$today.'csv'
$mail->addAttachment('./'.$filename, 'file.csv', 'base64', 'text/csv');
```

--solution--

```
 $today = date("Y-m-d");
 $filename = "file.csv";
 $filename2 = 'file'.$today.'csv';
 $mail->addAttachment($filename, $filename2);
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the second argument to the name you want to have? The first argument is the filepath. (God, their documentation is horrible)

Comment: I have tried that. And yes, i can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: I can only see `AddAttachment($path, $name = "", $encoding = "base64",
    $type = "application/octet-stream")` `string $path string $name string $encoding string $type` `Adds an attachment from a path on the filesystem. Returns false if the file could not be found or accessed.` in their methods documentation, so I can only guess. But my guess would be that the first argument is the full filepath and the second the name presented in the email. Even the answer to the same question says the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776073/phpmailer-sent-attachment-as-other-name

Comment: I've voted it to close as duplicate of above link.

Comment: I searched for similiar posts but didn't see this one at all. updating post with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite a duplicate as you know how to set both names, but you've simply got your filenames the wrong way around. Try this:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$filename = 'file'.$today.'csv'
$mail->addAttachment('./file.csv', $filename, 'base64', 'text/csv');
```

The docs on this method are [here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addAttachment).